# Use case of a Generic constructor

Tags: java

We can define a generic constructor like in the following example:

```
public class Example {
    public <T> Example(T t) {
        //...
    }
}
```

I found a article that has an example of a Generic constructor:

```
class Test {
    //Generics constructor
    public <T> Test(T item){
         System.out.println("Value of the item: " + item);
         System.out.println("Type of the item: " 
                 + item.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

But it does not make sense because the type `T` can be replaced with `String` and still work fine.

We can not use the type `T` out of the constructor. Also we can not return something from the constructor. So why is it even available for the devs? Can someone give me a use case of a generic constructor?

Comment: I think I would give the class the generic type too.
This sort of idiom can be used when creating things like Stacks.  A good source on generics is the generics chapter in Effective Java.

Comment: @Gavin I am not interested in making the class generic. The above code compiles and I want to know why.

Comment: It does not compile for me

Comment: @Antoniossss Declaring generic type on class is not what I am expecting. The above code compiles fine on java 8 and I just want to know why is it even available at first place. Because making constructor as generic makes no sense to me.

Comment: @roundAbout It clearly depends on what the constructor is doing. It might be even call a method where the generic type is required, so using "just" the parameter type `object` might not be enough. But this clearly depends on what the constructor is doing.

Comment: @Progman That's what I am asking for, just a simple example would be enough for me.

Comment: @roundAbout `public <T>Example(T t) { SomeOtherClass.someOtherMethod<T>(t); }`

Comment: It depends on usecase. It might be use for example to enforce argument matches like `<T> Clazz(T obj, List<T> siblings);`